# ajaxsubmit can't submit returns null

Tags: yii

I get an error 200. Form never gets posted, all fields return blank.  I also checked if the columns are required, i set everything to null. I have another form that looks like this and it works fine. Any ideas?

```
   <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'thisForm',
    )); ?>
//form
    <?php 
            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Add',
                    Yii::app()->createUrl("url/controller"),
                    array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'dataType'=>'text json',
                            'data'=>'js:$("#thisForm").serialize()',
                            'success'=>'js:function(data) {
                                if(data.status=="success")
                                     $.fn.yiiGridView.update("osb123");
                             }',
                            'error'=>'function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError);
                            }'
                    ));
            ?>

    public function actionController()
        {
            $model=new Model;

            if($_POST['Model'])
            {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Model'];
                $model->temporary_id = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
                $model->cost = floatval($_POST['Model']['cost']);
                $model->active = "Y";

                if($model->validate()){
                    echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=> 'success',
                            'data'=>var_dump($_POST['Model'])
                            ));
                }
                else{
                    $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
                    echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=> 'error', 'error'=>var_dump($_POST['Model'])));
                }
            }else echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'error','error'=>'Not Set'));

        }
```

Comment: I've edited your post. Please post the results you get.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the ajax button for `url` you set: `Yii::app()->createUrl("url/controller")` while usually the right syntax is `Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action")` Could you with debugging tool (Ctrl+Shift+I or F12) check the POST-request and see the actual url that has been generated by yii?
2. You have `beginWidget`, do you also have `endWidget` ?